# Inject secret value into helm values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I have a kubernetes deployment which consists out of several charts. To configure it for different environments I have multiple "deployment.yaml" files which I apply like this:
`helm upgrade -i mychart helm/mychart -f values/deploymentXY.yaml`.

Within the `values/deploymentXY.yaml` I have a structure like this:

```
subchart:
 configuration:
  param1: "foo"
  param2: "bar"
  param3: "supersecret"
```

How can I make param3 really secret if I want to upload my helm files to git? I can't change the subchart. I can apply a second secrets-deploymentYX.yaml which I won't upload to git, I can create secrets  etc.
But how can I then replace param3 by a secured value without loosing the other params? I feel that I miss something. Any idea?

Thank you very much in forward!!!

Comment: How secure do you want it?  You can use the `helm install -f` option multiple times, if the only constraint is the secret shouldn't be checked in; `helm get values` and `kubectl get secret` will both be able to retrieve it (subject to RBAC controls and base64 decoding) if you use it with Helm at all.